# MAMP config settings reset every time I restart

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm running MAMP Pro v2.1.1 on OSX 10.8.5

I like to modify a couple settings for phpMyAdmin by modifying the settings in `/Library/Application Support/absolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

This works just fine, but every time I restart MAMP, the settings revert back to the defaults. It's really annoying.

I know that the php.ini file and other files are meant to be edited with MAMP's built-in editor. But there does not appear to be an option for phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I had the same issue... Pretty annoying but I found out after emailing them that the file at `/Library/Application Support/absolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` is basically a temporary placeholder for your settings, inasmuch as whenever you start up MAMP the contents of the file at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` is read and copied into it, overriding whatever's already there.

That said, **here's what to do**:

---

1. Stop all servers and quit MAMP (completely)
2. Make your changes to the file located at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`
3. Open MAMP again and start all servers

---

The settings from the file you just edited should now be copied into the one that's actually read by MAMP and should take effect immediately.

For instance, I prefer to not enable the AJAX feature, so I did this:

1. Shut down the servers
2. Closed MAMP (entirely)
3. Opened the file `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`
4. Added `$cfg['AjaxEnable'] = false;` to the file
5. Saved the file
6. Reopened MAMP
7. Started the servers

... and all was well.

Comment: Weird. I'll try it. But when I change the settings in the config.inc.php that's in Application Support those changes work. So it can't be irrelevant. Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: @Emerson Yeah maybe I said that wrong. It's not that the one you're referring to (the logical one) is _irrelevant_ because you're right: that's where the settings are read from. But from what I gather, whenever you start up MAMP (PRO) the contents of the file I listed is read and copied into the file you listed, overriding whatever's already there. Like I can't stand the AJAX feature because I like to see the query data all the time, so I shut down the servers, closed MAMP, opened the file I listed, added `$cfg['AjaxEnable'] = false;` to it, saved it, reopened MAMP, and all was well.

Comment: Yup. It works! If you have second, maybe add your comment to the answer because it really helps demystify what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very late answer but problem still persists in OS Sierra. So, this is what worked for me -

You can change the owner of phpMyAdmin by using this command -

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpMyAdmin
```

Replace the directory path of phpMyAdmin in case you installed it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what worked was to change the configuration of the `config.inc.php` in the `phpMyAdmin5` folder instead of the `phpMyAdmin` one.

So, what I did was:

1. Shut down the servers with the "Stop" button or using command `cd /Applications/MAMP/bin && ./stop.sh`.
2. Quit MAMP application.
3. Opened the file `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin5/config.inc.php`
4. Change or add configuration
5. Save the file with `Command + S`.
6. Start MAMP again.

Also, if you want to easily modify the `config.inc.php` file, you can modify all the configuration you want in the phpMyAdmin interface and then export the settings as a PHP file, as shown in the image:

[image]

Then, you can open the downloaded file and paste its content at the end of the `config.inc.php` file. Then save and start MAMP!